# Update status in every 5 seconds when app in foreground in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to update my online status in firebase periodically but when is in foreground but when it's gone in background then i have to set the status offline.
So Please help me how to manage.

Here is the code through which i update it on firebase

```
private void fireStoreUpdate() {
    PreferenceManager preferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());
    String chefId = preferenceManager.getChefId();
    String restuarantId = preferenceManager.getMerchantId();
    Restaurant restaurant = new Restaurant("online", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), chefId, restuarantId);
    // Firestore
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("restaurants").document("Restaurant ID : " + restuarantId).set(restaurant);
}
```

It's updating but how do I make it so it repeats it every 5 seconds?

Comment: Take a look to this link. It shows you how to use FirebaseJobDispatcher to schedule a Job and repeat it every N seconds
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android#user-content-firebase-jobdispatcher-

Comment: Use a `LifecycleObserver` and call this method each 5 seconds . You can use `Timer` .

Comment: thanks, i will try.

Comment: ADM how i use LifecycleObserver for this repeated task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Handler and execute your function every "x" time. When the lifecycle is onPause(), you just stop this handler and when the app is back to foreground in the onResume() execute the handler again.

I am gonna show you the approach with a simple Activity

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final long EVERY_FIVE_SECOND = 5000;

    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Executing the handler
        executeHandler();
    }

    private void executeHandler(){
        //If the handler and runnable are null we create it the first time.
        if(handler == null && runnable == null){
            handler = new Handler();

           runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Updating firebase store
                    fireStoreUpdate();
                    //And we execute it again
                    handler.postDelayed(this, EVERY_FIVE_SECOND);
                }
            };
        }
        //If the handler and runnable are not null, we execute it again when the app is resumed.
        else{
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, EVERY_FIVE_SECOND);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //execute the handler again.
        executeHandler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //we remove the callback
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        //and we set the status to offline.
        updateStatusToOffline();
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: but it's working when i stay in that activity but if i move it another activity it will not work . I actually want for my application

Comment: Thanks. i just used this code in my application class and it's working.

Comment: Hello Shubham Dubey. I was writing you about use it in the application class.

Comment: thanks bro it's working, but how could i improve it in better way is there any suggestion

Comment: I think another approach could be using a job scheduler and execute it when the app is working and kill it when the app is not working: FirebaseJobDispatcher is a good library for that.

Comment: i will try that